# Extjs 4.2 compile mvc existing project

Tags: extjs, minify, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd, yui-compressor

My project developped in Extjs 4.2 (MVC structure) , I want to build it with Sencha cmd I tried this command line : `sencha compile --classpath=path/extjs-source,path/src,path/extjs/ux,path/project --options=debug:false include --all and concatenate  --compress --output-file=output.js`
When I integarte output.js file in my Php project I have thes error : `Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined`
can you halp me to do this correctly

Answer (score 0):

If your project is located at D:\WORK then on sencha cmd, navigate to this path 
and run command `Sencha app build` . If execution of this is successful, you will get a build of your project in build\production folder inside your sencha project.